# Garbage Collection on Javascript Client side

Tags: javascript, optimization, garbage-collection

I am currently having some issues with GC on the javascript client side.
Here is an image of Firfox with the GC issue.

[GC graph on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTxh0.png)

If you look at the image it is every tick where the Garbage collection is happening.

So this is the code that is being called every tick in the javascript.

```
socket.on('serverTellPlayerMove', function (count, userData, countEnergy, strEnergy) {
    var tempUsers = userData.split(",");
    console.log(userData);
    var visible = [];
    var overall = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        if ((Number(tempUsers[overall]) == 1) == true) {
            visible.push({
                p: Number(tempUsers[0 + overall]) == 1,
                kills: Number(tempUsers[1 + overall]),
                x: Number(tempUsers[2 + overall]),
                y: Number(tempUsers[3 + overall]),
                angle: Number(tempUsers[4 + overall]),
                hue: Number(tempUsers[5 + overall]),
                radius: Number(tempUsers[6 + overall]),
                name: tempUsers[7 + overall],
                dead: parseInt(tempUsers[8 + overall]) == 1,
                dying: parseInt(tempUsers[9 + overall]) == 1
            });
            overall += 10;
        } else {
            visible.push({
                x: Number(tempUsers[0 + overall]),
                y: Number(tempUsers[1 + overall]),
                angle: Number(tempUsers[2 + overall]),
                hue: Number(tempUsers[3 + overall]),
                radius: Number(tempUsers[4 + overall]),
                name: tempUsers[5 + overall],
                dead: Number(tempUsers[6 + overall]) == 1,
                dying: Number(tempUsers[7 + overall]) == 1
            });
            overall += 8;
        }

    }
    console.log(userData);
    console.log(visible);
    var playerData;
    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
        if (visible[i].p) {
            //console.log("mwahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha");
            playerData = visible[i];
            i = visible.length;
        }
    }
    if (userData == "") {} else {
        if (playerType == 'player') {
            console.log(playerData);
            // HOW MUCH YOU MOVED BY:
            //console.log(playerData.y);
            var xoffset = player.x - playerData.x;
            var yoffset = player.y - playerData.y;
            player.x = playerData.x;
            player.y = playerData.y;
            player.angle = playerData.angle;
            player.hue = playerData.hue;
            player.xoffset = isNaN(xoffset) ? 0 : xoffset;
            player.yoffset = isNaN(yoffset) ? 0 : yoffset;
            player.dead = playerData.dead;
            document.getElementById("killsText").innerHTML = "Kills: " + playerData.kills;
        }
    }

    // DEATH ANIM:
    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
        if (visible[i].dying) {
            createExplosion(visible[i].x, visible[i].y);
        }
    }

    // DEATH ANIM:
    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
        if (visible[i].dying) {
            createExplosion(visible[i].x, visible[i].y);
        }
    }

    users = visible;
    var energiesList = [];
    var allEnergies = 0;
    if (strEnergy != "") {
        var tempEnergies = strEnergy.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < countEnergy; i++) {
            energiesList.push({
                x: Number(tempEnergies[0 + allEnergies]),
                y: Number(tempEnergies[1 + allEnergies]),
                radius: Number(tempEnergies[2 + allEnergies]),
                index: Number(tempEnergies[3 + allEnergies]),
                animate: tempEnergies[4 + allEnergies] === "true",
                hue: Number(tempEnergies[5 + allEnergies]),
                room: tempEnergies[6 + allEnergies]
            });
            allEnergies += 7;
        }
    }
    console.log(energiesList);
    if (energiesList == "") {} else {
        for (var i = 0; i < energiesList.length; ++i) {
            var energyT = energiesList[i];
            //console.log(energyT);
            if (energyT.animate) {
                energyT.animScale = 0;
            } else {
                if (energies[energyT.index] != undefined)
                    energyT.animScale = energies[energyT.index].animScale;
            }
            energies[energyT.index] = energyT;
        }
    }
});
```

Where "count" is the number of users, userData and strEnergy is the users and food as a string. the user string looks something like "1,0,100,100,50,50,22,somename,0,0" and it is split then pushed into an object to be used later on.

The Cycle collection depending on the computer is 0.52ms~100ms. If there are any methods of decreasing this GC that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you are creating lots of objects (and arrays), which i'll bet is the main problem. recycle your objects, especially the ones created in-loop, and you'll see a boost. there are a lot of articles about this, google up.

Comment: `function clean(obj){ for(i in obj) delete obj[i]; return obj;}` can help, but 9/10 times you can just clobber the old property values without deleting them.